# Text Adventure game not showing text elements

Tags: javascript, game-development

I am a beginner programmer and am attempting to create a Text Adventure with javascript, however, the text will not show and I couldn't find any obvious errors. could someone plaese help.

js
const textElement = document.getElementById('text')
const optionButtonsElement = document.getElementById('option-buttons')

```
let state = {}

function startGame() {
    state = {}
    showTextNode(1)
}

function showTextNode(textNodeIndex) {
    const textNode = textNodes.find(textNode.id === textNodeIndex)
    textElement.innerText = textNode.text
    while (optionButtonsElement.firstChild) {
        optionButtonsElement.removeChild(optionButtonsElement.firstChild)
}

function selectOption(option) {
    
}
    
    

const textNodes = [
    {
        id: 1,
        text: "You wake up in a room you've never seen before. Getting out of bed, you note the silver, almost royal, color scheme of the room.",
        option: [
        {
        text: 'Examine the Room',
        setState: { RoomKnowledge: true },
        nextText: 2
        }
        ]
    }
    {
    id: 2
    }
]

startGame()
```

html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
        <title>Test</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
        <script src="game.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <div id="text"></div>
            <div id="option-buttons" class="btn-grid">
                <button class="btn">Option 1</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 2</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 3</button>
                <button class="btn">Option 4</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to add your HTML.

Comment: Running this code as-is, (and mocking up some html) gave some immediate errors; do you use your console/developer tools?